# How to search records with the special characters using like operator in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I have a search bar with all the alphabetic characters where users can click any of them to get relevant results.

e.g if I click on "A" it will get results starting with all "Albert"

```
ALL A B c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z Æ Å Ø Ö Ä 0-9
```

So, MySQL query becomes `LIKE "a%"`

but the problem is, it also brings those records which are starting with the special character "Å", I don't want these results. It should only appear when users click and search for them like using this `LIKE "Å%"`

how is that possible?

Update: My database schema and tables all are UTF-8 collation.

Comment: Use collation that distinguishes these characters.

Comment: Try to `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8')` at the top of your script

Comment: UTF-8 is a charset, not a collation. A charset may have different collations which are used for comparison and sorting. For example utf8_bin is a collation of utf8 charset that is case and accent sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**BINARY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) operator to search for a string based on its binary representation (etc. *byte-by-byte* rather *character-by-character*):

Like this (just replace with your table information)

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE BINARY name LIKE 'A%'
```

The above searches byte-by-byte rather than character-by-character, which solves at least my similar problems. I'm using it to search through nativenames of countries and similar information.

**UPDATE**

For case-sensitive and UTF-8 data you can give a try to this:

```
SELECT name FROM `mytable` WHERE name COLLATE utf8_bin LIKE 'a%';   // returned only lower a's latin
SELECT name FROM `mytable` WHERE name COLLATE utf8_bin LIKE 'ä%';   // returned only lower ä's
```

Comment: waho great solution, i also want to get all records starting from small "a" or capital "A"?

Comment: can you please mention or update your above query so all record appear doesn't depend on case sensitive.

Comment: @Naeem, i dont think it's possible with just using BINARY since its search is case insensitive.

Comment: then i can use two clauses :)

Comment: I wish it could be done in just one query and one universal solution for this kind of queries :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Like like this

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
SELECT name FROM `mytable` WHERE name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%a%'; 
SELECT name FROM `mytable` WHERE name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%ä%';
}
```

%a%  == it will search all started with a

%ä% == it will search all started with ä